# Mysql, list of values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, list

I have a table that stores information about categories ('cats' let's say) and another table (say 'cars' meaning it stores infos about cars - a lame example, but that doesn't matter) that has a column called 'parent_cat_id' which should reference 'id' col in 'cats'.
Now comes the problem: any car from 'cars' could belong to more then one category.
There's an obvious, but very lame, solution: store in parent_cat_id a delimited list of numbers, but, if i apply that, I couldn't have any foreign key constraint and should jump into parsing these values. Although parsing isn't such a big deal, but I can't believe MySQL doesn't have anything pre-built.
Also it looks like selecting cars by category will involve some substring and other things.
Having no foreign key is a far bigger problem.
The only thing I was able to find is a 'SET' type, but it should be pre-defined what values it can store during database development, also it can have only 64 pre-defined values while there could be 100s of categories.

Comment: Look for FIND_IN_SET,crystal balling it.Also take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The normal way of modeling this kind of [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship is to introduce a third table (a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)) that holds information about relationships between items in the two other tables.

In your example you would have three tables:

- Category
- Cars
- CarCategory which has foreign keys to both the primary keys in Category and Cars

This is pretty fundamental relational modeling and you might want to look at a nice tutorial or book to get further knowledge about the concepts.

Just as you recognize storing delimited lists of keys is a bad idea as it breaks the model.